# Should I specify both <a rel="alternate"> and <link rel="alternate"> for multilingual websites?

Tags: html, multilingual, hreflang

I have read [Google's recommendations](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) regarding `<link rel="alternate">` in the `<head>` for multilingual websites.

As far as I know, we can also use `rel="alternate"` on `<a>` tags, and so far I've been using this technique on visible links to switch between different languages of my website like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/en/" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" lang="en">English</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/fr/" rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" lang="fr">Français</a>
    </li>
</li>
```

The Google Webmaster Tools answer doesn't mention this technique in regards to `<a>` tags though, so should I use `<link>` tags in the header in addition to `<a>` tags in the body, even though they are redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely keep the `<link>` tags in your `<head>` section. I've never read anywhere that Google actually acknowledges `rel="alternate"` on `<a>` tags. Also many other bots may only retrieve the `<head>` of your documents, so if those `<link>` tags aren't in the header, they may never actually see them. But I don't think that having the `rel="alternate"` on your `<a>` tags **in addition** to having them in the `HEAD` would make any difference.